# Need to find the last value in a nested MONGODB document

Tags: mongodb

[SCREENSHOT OF DOCUMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfSHP.png)I have a nested document in a mongoDB named stages. There are numerous objects within this document depending on how long a produce lasts (sometimes 3, other times 4 +). Each of these objects contains 3 values: name, TIME_COMPLETED and result. I want to created a shell command which will allow to find the last TIME_COMPLETED value that is entered in .

```
db.completedTasks.find({"stages.TIME_COMPLETED":"2018-11-27T10:27:20.854Z" })
```

This command allows me to accurately search for a specific TIME_COMPLETED value, however I would like to find the last value in the stages document.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the sample document

Comment: If your `TIME_COMPLETED` field is in ISOformat then you can sort the records in descending order and get the first entry.

Comment: A screenshot of the table is now included

Comment: Will `TIME_COMPLETED`  be the latest with every insertion? Or it may be less or more ?

Comment: Always the latest